Matplotlib issue with colorbar using subplot_mosaic and make_axes_locatable
I want to create a figure using subplot_mosaic which is very useful to organize plots. However with my code, when I plot the figure, I don't see the colorbar value and title. This is probably due to make_axes_locatable and constrained_layout=True, but in my case I don't have the choice to use it.
Moreover, when I save it, I get the entire plot but the aspect ratio is not preserved (5,7).
This is my code :
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable


def plot2d(data, ax):
    im = ax.imshow(data, aspect="auto")

    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label="DATA")


fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 7)
ax = fig.subplot_mosaic([["D1"]])

plot2d(np.random.rand(10, 1000), ax["D1"])
plt.savefig("foo3.pdf", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=100)

plt.show()


This will save a pdf image with the colorbar values, title and ticks.
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable

def plot2d(data, ax, cbar_title="", cbar_ticks=None):
    im = ax.imshow(data, aspect="auto")

    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label=cbar_title)
    if cbar_ticks:
        cbar.set_ticks(cbar_ticks)
    return cbar

fig = plt.figure(constrained_layout=True)
fig.set_size_inches(5, 7)
ax = fig.subplot_mosaic([["D1"]])

data = np.random.rand(10, 1000)
cbar_ticks = [0, 0.5, 1]  # Example ticks for the color bar
cbar_title = "DATA"
colorbar = plot2d(data, ax["D1"], cbar_title=cbar_title, cbar_ticks=cbar_ticks)
colorbar.set_label(cbar_title)  # Optional, if you want to set label again

plt.savefig("foo3.pdf", bbox_inches="tight", dpi=100)
plt.show()

Please, accept if it was helpful.
Thanks,
